# Android user-behaviour-analytics : Programatically record the user interaction from the application

Tags: android

I want to know how the users are interacting with my application, how they are navigating in the app. There are analytics-library like [Fullstory](https://www.fullstory.com/features/)(only for web) and [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/). I wanted to know:
1. What are the other analytics tools for android that records user session?
2. If I want to achieve this without any libraries how can I record user interactions programmatically and log the session to server and what are possible architecture design to achieve this on android.

Comment: Your first uestion is a library request, which is off topic.  Your second is just way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Answers Events by Fabric which offers custom events: https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html#id12

Fabric also includes Crashlytics which tracks app crashes and provides frameworks to track app growth, user engagement which certainly makes it a worthwhile option to consider because of the many features (even if you only need Answers Events for now).

[image: Answers Events setup]

Comment: I am using GA and some other tools to track events. I want to record  user session(by creating video) while user launch and navigate through the app. Please check fullstory and appsee.